# Where can I find the manual for 1990’s Die Hard?

Tags: die-hard

I found my original floppy disk for 1990’s Die Hard (among other stuff), and in a fit of nostalgia I decided to create an image and give DOSBox a shot.

[image: Die Hard floppy disk]

However, I’ve long lost the box and manual. The controls aren’t quite intuitive, and while some digging has shown, for example, that “S” is for searching; I can’t yet find how to stop aiming my gun.

Plus, rumor has it that I’ll need it to get out of the starting floor. Something I didn’t recall from nearly three decades ago.

I tried searching the web, without luck. It’s hard enough to filter results for the 1990 version.

**Where can I find the manual?**

Failing that, where can I find out the game’s keyboard controls?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check it out ;) Found it. I thought it'd be a lot harder than that, but hope this helps in your nostalgia! :)

[http://www.gamesdatabase.org/Media/SYSTEM/Commodore_64/manual/Formated/Die_Hard_-*1990*-_Activision.pdf](http://www.gamesdatabase.org/Media/SYSTEM/Commodore_64/manual/Formated/Die_Hard_-_1990_-_Activision.pdf)